# Turbulenz engine install python tools

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, turbulenz

I am trying to `Turbulenz` however im having some problems installing the tools:

`cgfx2json` and `NvTriStrip`

When i am in the `env` and run `sudo python manage.py tools` i get the following error:

```
Creating: /var/www/learningbank_turbulenz/tools/bin/linux64
Executing: make
make -C cgfx2json/
make[1]: Entering directory `/var/www/learningbank_turbulenz/tools/cgfx2json'
g++  obj/release/cgfx2json.o  obj/release/jsmin.o  -lCg -lCgGL -lGL -lstdc++ -lpthread -o bin/release/cgfx2json
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bin/release/cgfx2json] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/www/learningbank_turbulenz/tools/cgfx2json'
make: *** [cgfx2json/] Error 2
 >> [ERROR]   - Command 'make' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Please note that i am on a `ubuntu 14.04` machine